transformers[agents] library doesn't work properly on Linux systems
I'm following a huggingface tutorial Huggingface agent 101. I installed the library by executing pip install transformers[agents] on colab and when I imported the tool using from transformers import tool I get the following error: AttributeError: module transformers has no attribute tool
Now when I checked the transformers library by run dir(transformers), it indeed doesn't have any tool function or class.
Contrary to this when I ran the same set of commands on my Windows-11 machine, it worked and had tool listed too.
Just to be sure on my hypothesis, I ran the same code on Kaggle notebook as well, it too had the same issue as that of Google colab
The python version for the 3 environments are:

Windows11: python 3.10.14
Kaggle notebook: python 3.10.14
Google colab: python 3.10.12

Any help will be highly appreciated.

could you please post the full error?

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 # from transformers import tool
----> 2 from transformers import tool
ImportError: cannot import name 'tool' from 'transformers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/init.py)

sorry for the delay responding. can you confirm the versions of transformers that are being installed (pip freeze)? and have you tried uninstalling transformers and reinstalling? I would also confirm that the colab and kaggle versions are using the desired venv (python --version)
